# Google API Key hits max request limit despite billing enabled

Tags: .net, google-maps-api-3, webrequest, google-distancematrix-api

I believe I have done everything to properly setup access to the Distance Matrix API.

First, I created a project and a billing account. That billing account is enabled on this project.

Next, I enabled the Distance Matrix API and created an unrestricted (for now) API key.

This is how I am making calls to the Google Distance Matrix API:

```
var requestUri = string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?units=imperial&mode=driving&origins={0}&destinations={1}&KEY={2}", originAddress, destinationAddress, apiKey);
var request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
var response = request.GetResponse();
return XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
```

The XDocument that is returned from this method is then parsed and the distance I am requesting to be calculated is extracted.

However, after 2500 requests, I am receiving an `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` with this message:

`You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. We recommend registering for a key at the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_`

Have I overlooked any steps in setting up the API key or project/billing account? Or can anybody see something I am doing wrong in my code?

Comment: `KEY=` needs to be lowercase `key=`

Comment: what does your google account say regarding your total hits?

Comment: @Coder it is not hitting at all. I should've included that. It is just telling me that I reached my limit.

Comment: I will try @geocodezip suggestion today and see if that works

Comment: any update?? @terbubbs

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing with the client JS API and Directions API requests. I hit the limit two afternoons in a row, but the usage isn't showing up at all in the Google API dashboard.I did find this URL for Premium customers: https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/usage-dashboard

Comment: @Coder geocodezip's suggestion was correct

Comment: @geocodezip feel free to leave your comment as an answer and i can mark it correct. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KEY=` needs to be lowercase `key=`

```
var requestUri = string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?units=imperial&mode=driving&origins={0}
                                &destinations={1}&KEY={2}", originAddress, destinationAddress, apiKey);
```

should be:

```
var requestUri = string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?units=imperial&mode=driving&origins={0}
                                &destinations={1}&key={2}", originAddress, destinationAddress, apiKey);
```