# Google APIs - API Key not Counting Against Queries

Tags: google-api, google-distancematrix-api

I've come to you today in hopes of getting some support in regards to the Google Distance Matrix API. Currently I'm using this in a very simple way with a Web Services request through an HTTP interface and am having no problems getting results. Unfortunately my project seems to be running into Query limits due to the 2,500 query Quota limit. I have added Billing to the project to allow for going over 2,500 queries, and it reflects that increased quota in my project. What's funky though is that the console is not showing any usage and so I'm not sure if these requests are being ran against what I have set up.

I am using a single API Key for the project which is present in my requests, and as I said before the requests ARE working, but again I'm hoping to see if someone can shed some light as to why I might not be seeing my queries reflected in my usage, and to see how I can verify that my requests are being run under the project for which I have attached billing.

If there is any information I can provide to help assist in finding an answer, please feel free to let me know and I'll be happy to give what information I can.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging I was able to find the following relevant thread to answer my question:

[Google API Key hits max request limit despite billing enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724833/google-api-key-hits-max-request-limit-despite-billing-enabled)